# i am getting runtime error vecause of commented if statement how to solve?

Tags: runtime-error

```
    vector<vector<int>> floodFill(vector<vector<int>>& ig, int sr, int sc, int nc) {
        int n= ig.size();
        int m=ig[0].size();
       // cout<<m<<endl;
        queue<pair<int,int>> q;
        if(ig[sr][sc]==nc)
             return ig;
        int t = ig[sr][sc];
        q.push({sr,sc});
        while(!q.empty()){
            pair<int,int>v=q.front();
            q.pop();
            ig[v.first][v.second]=nc;
            if(v.first>0){
                if(ig[v.first-1][v.second]==t)
                {
                    q.push({v.first-1,v.second});
                }
            }
            if(v.first<n){
                if(ig[v.first+1][v.second]==t)
                {
                    q.push({v.first+1,v.second});
                }
            }
         /*if(v.second>0){  
             if(ig.at(v.first).at(v.second-1) ==t)
                {
                    q.push({v.first,v.second-1});
                }
            }
           */
            if(v.second<m){
                if(ig[v.first][v.second+1]==t)
                {
                    q.push({v.first,v.second+1});
                }
            }
         
        }
        return ig;
    }
```

how to solve this? error is in the third if statement which i have commented out.when i commented the third if statement it was compiled properly and when it was included it shows runtime error .

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Which programming language is this? What have you tried to debug the problem? And can you share the full and exact error message?

Comment: this is a c++ code

Comment: this error is shown by the compiler : Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address 0xbebebebebebebebe for type 'int', which requires 4 byte alignment (stl_vector.h) 0xbebebebebebebebe: note: pointer points here <memory cannot be printed> SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:9

Comment: this is question link:

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: leetcode.com/problems/flood-fill

Comment: just shared the question link ........................ code is attached above can you run it once and check?

Comment: the runtime error is because of third if statement ..... when the third if statment is commented out code iss getting compiled . when the third statement is included it shows run time error

Comment: **Please add all clarification to your question by editing it** - don't use the comment section for essential information

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `v.second-1` because it's out of bound if `v.second` equals 0. You need to handle the bound of indices before accessing invalid (negative) indices.

Comment: but the condition is v.second >0 so how it will become equal to 0

Comment: Yes, you're completely right. Please, edit the post to add a sample test with a screenshot of the output.

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/flood-fill/     This is link to the question

Comment: this error is shown by the compiler  :                                                                                     Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address 0xbebebebebebebebe for type 'int', which requires 4 byte alignment (stl_vector.h)
0xbebebebebebebebe: note: pointer points here
<memory cannot be printed>
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:9

Comment: I think `if(ig.at(v.first).at(v.second-1) ==t)` is wrong because `at` returns a reference to the element not the element itself. Try to access vectors by brackets as you do in the other three conditions.